# Bounty wasn't awarded, and badge wasn't given.

Tags: support, badges, bounty-awards

I opened a bounty on my question a while back and gave a maximum of 450 bounty points. I **really** wanted some great answers and I got them. :)

[How do you organize your projects?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40394/how-do-you-organize-your-projects)

Two things went wrong:

A) Amy P never got the bounty awarded to her. She is still at around 200 reputation points.

B) I never got the Benefactor badge.

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067) from the [bounty faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/148672)

> **What happens if there's no answer after the bounty period?**
>
> **What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered?**
>
> **What is automatic awarding?**
>
> At the end of the bounty period, if
>   the bounty starter has not manually
>   awarded the bounty, eligible answers
>   can be automatically awarded half the
>   bounty amount. The criteria for an
>   answer to be eligible for automatic
>   awarding are as follows:
>
> The answer must be given after the
>   bounty was started The answer must
>   have a score of at least +2 If two or
>   more eligible answers have the same
>   score, the oldest answer is awarded
>   the bounty.
>
> If no answers meet these criteria, the
>   bounty ends without it being awarded
>   to any answer, and is not refunded to
>   the bounty starter.
>
> An accepted answer that does not meet
>   the above criteria is still ignored by
>   the automatic-awarding system.

It looks like the bounty was automatically given to [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40394/how-do-you-organize-your-projects/41938#41938) by Alex.

This explains why it went to alex. It also explains why no badge for you. Automatic awards don't count because the benefactor badge goes for the "First bounty you **manually** awarded on
 your own question"

Comment: But I accepted the answer a full 24+ hours before the timer went out. Is there someone to verify this?

Comment: @Sergio. Accepting the answer isn't the same as awarding a bounty. See "How do I award a bounty?" In [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067) on the bounty faq

Comment: Oh drag... :( I feel bad for Amy P. She really deserved that fat bounty I laid out.

Comment: @Sergio - for what it's worth, you can start another bounty... If you are feeling generous.

Comment: Too bad you can't change the bounty like you can the accepted answer...